# Change shorcut for console switch

Tags: debian, linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to change the shortcut set by default on my Debian 6.0 (server) for tty switch.

By defautl it is ALT + Fx, but i just want to switch to Fx.

I guess it involves modification of Xorg, but i can't get which file to modify. I didn't find any other topics on the subject, but maybe my keywords were wrong.

Anyway, thanks for reading, hope someone may help me !

Comment: it has nothing to do with Xorg. Probably, there should be some kernel parameter.

Comment: this could come really handy for virtual machines as I always end up switching tty on the host instead of the guest

Comment: I will check for Kernel options tommorow, but as it isn't mandatory on the project, a faster solution should be better suited. Anyway thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the action of the function keys, you'll need to create and load a custom keymap. You'll wamt to take a look at the `loadkeys(1)` command. There are some good examples here: http://luv.asn.au/overheads/virtualconsoles.html#keymap which I found easy to follow. For more in-depth information, take a look at the keyboard and console HOWTO: http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.html